# Sylius project and synfony server pkcs12 error

Tags: php, symfony, server, sylius

When i try symfony server:start i have `pkcs12: decryption password incorrect`
I apreciate some thougths, im am completely stuck on this.
I'm using ubuntu 18.04, php 7.2 , php-fpm.
Thanks.

Comment: please, add the used sylius/symfony versions to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Install symfony globally solves the problem

Comment: please, add how to install symfony globally for who don't know how to do it